# Finding out which rows are inserted , updated or deleted using triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named indication in Database and it has three columns `Name`, `Age`, and `Enable`.

I want to create a trigger that inserts an alarm into my alarm table whenever the `Age` is under 18 and `Enable` is true, I want to check the record on the indication table at the exact moment that it has been inserted, that way I can check whether it should be inserted in alarm or not.

I found `COLUMNS_UPDATED (Transact-SQL)` on MSDN and it works for updated columns, is there the same thing for `ROWS_UPDATED`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always set your trigger to respond to only an `INSERT` action, with

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Whatever_I ON dbo.YourTable FOR INSERT
AS
... (body of trigger)
```

Be aware `FOR INSERT` is the same as `AFTER INSERT`. You also have the option of `INSTEAD OF`, but with that you have to perform the data modification yourself. There is no `BEFORE` trigger in SQL Server.

In some cases it is very convenient to handle more than one action at once because the script for the different actions is similar--why write three triggers when you can write just one? So in the case where your trigger looks more like this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Whatever_IUD ON dbo.YourTable FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
... (body of trigger)
```

Then you don't automatically know it was an insert in the body. In this case, you can detect whether it's an insert similar to this:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted) BEGIN
   --It's an INSERT.
END
```

Or, if you want to determine which of the three DML operations it is:

```sql
DECLARE @DataOperation char(1);
SET @DataOperation =
   CASE
      WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted) THEN 'D'
      WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted) THEN 'I'
      ELSE 'U'
   END
;
```

Triggers still run if a DML operation affects no rows (for example, `UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET Column = '' WHERE 1 = 0`). In this case, you can't tell whether it was an update, delete, or insert--but since no modification occurred, it doesn't matter.

**A Special Note**

It's worth mentioning that in SQL Server, triggers fire once per *operation*, NOT once per *row*. This means that the `Inserted` and `Deleted` meta-tables will have as many rows in them during trigger execution as there are rows affected by the operation. Be careful and don't write triggers that assume there will only be one row.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I think you have to increase your knowledge on the way triggers work, and what the different type of triggers are.

You can create a trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Indication_Ins 
   ON  Indication 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Insert Alarms (column1, column2) Select value1, value2 from inserted where Age < 18 and Enable = 1
END
```

This should basically do what you are looking for, and from what I understand from your quesion.

**UPDATE:**

Basically triggers can fire on INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE or any combination of the three, You can also set it to fire 'FOR/AFTER' the event (of which both actually means AFTER), or INSTEAD OF the event. A trigger will always have "internal" or meta-tables on the event.

These tables are `inserted` and `deleted`

The `inserted` table is basically all the `new` records that is applied to the table, and the `deleted` table have all the records that will be removed. In the case of the `UPDATE` event, the `inserted` table will have all the new values and `deleted` will have all the old values.

The `inserted` table will be empty on a `DELETE` trigger, and the `deleted` table will be empty on an `INSERT` trigger

Triggers can affect performance drastically if not used properly, so use it wisely.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have some factually incorrect information in your answer. SQL Server does not support `BEFORE` triggers. There are only two kinds: `FOR/AFTER` and `INSTEAD OF`. Also, note that the `Inserted` and `Deleted` meta-tables **exist** during every DML operation, whether `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`. It's just a matter of which ones have any rows.

Comment: You are correct, I  don't know why I thought at that time that there are Before triggers. It is `FOR/AFTER` which is the same thing, and `INSTEAD OF` triggers. I've updated my answer to be correct