# SQL TRIGGER detect UPDATED or DELETED

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Here my code to create trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGERNAME ON [TABLENAME]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
     --[SQL STATEMENTS]
END
```

In the SQL statement, how can I check things like:

```
if (a row is updated) {
    -- do something
} 
else if (a row is deleted) {
    -- do something else
}
```

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/25279318/finding-out-which-rows-are-inserted-updated-or-deleted-using-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279318/finding-out-which-rows-are-inserted-updated-or-deleted-using-triggers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding out which rows are inserted , updated or deleted using triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279318/finding-out-which-rows-are-inserted-updated-or-deleted-using-triggers)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRIGGERNAME] ON [TABLENAME]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DELETED INT, @UPDATED INT
    SELECT @DELETED = COUNT(*) FROM [deleted]
    SELECT @UPDATED = COUNT(*) FROM [inserted]
    IF @UPDATED > 0
            PRINT ' inserted  '
        END
    ELSE IF @DELETED > 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT ' deleted '
        END
END
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the trigger is only for insert/delete:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
   -- I am an insert
ELSE
   -- I am a delete
```

But if you want to create the trigger for update and delete action, you can try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TRIGGERNAME] ON [TABLENAME]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
      BEGIN
        PRINT 'I am an update'
      END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      PRINT 'I am a delete'
    END
END
```

You can see [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to help you more.

Answer (score -1):

In oracle you can write like

CREATE TRIGGER [TRIGGERNAME] ON [TABLENAME]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

```
IF INSERTING    THEN
-- Some business logic

END IF;

IF UPDATING    THEN
-- Some business logic
END IF;

IF DELETING    THEN
-- Some business logic
END IF;
```

END

Comment: This question is not tagged with `oracle`